# Uploading image with form-data, using nodeJs, angularJs, mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am developing a form, which will have form-data along with image.
I am able to save image using multer
And also able to save image-path to mongoose.
But I am unable to save array-data to mongoose.
**Angular Template**

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data>
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="product.productName" placeholder="Enter Product Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Product Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="product.productDescription" placeholder="Enter product Description">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Product Thumbnail</label>
<input type="file" id="file"><br><br>
</div>
 <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="val in product.productStock">
 <div class="pull-right" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()" style="color:red; cursor: pointer;margin-right: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-times fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>

            <h4><i class="fa fa-clone" aria-hidden="true"></i> Product Variant</h4>
            <hr>
            <label>size</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="val.size" placeholder="Enter product size">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="val.price" placeholder="Enter price">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Color</label>

            <select ng-model="val.color" class="form-control">
              <option value="red">Red</option>
              <option value="green">Green</option>
              <option value="black">Black</option>
              <option value="brown">Brown</option>
              <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Quantity</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="val.quantity" placeholder="Enter quantity">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Image</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="val.imagePaths" placeholder="Enter image path">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Stock status</label>
          <select ng-model="val.inStock" class="form-control">
            <option value="Availble">Availble</option>
            <option value="Not Availble">Not Availble</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
```

**Model**

```
var productsSchema = new Schema({
    productName: {type: String, required: false},
    productDescription: {type: String, required: false},
    productThumbnail: {type: String, required:false},
    productStock: [
    {
        size: {type: Number, required: false},
        color: {type: String, required: false}
    }
    ]
)}
```

**Angular Controller**

```
$scope.product = {};
$scope.newProduct = function(){
  var formData = new FormData;
  for(key in $scope.product){
    formData.append(key, $scope.product[key]);
  } 
  //getting the files
  var file = $('#file')[0].files[0];
  formData.append('image', file);

  //Post data
  $http.post('http://localhost:3000/products/api/new-product',formData,{
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
  }).then(function(res){
    $scope.item = res.data;
  });

  console.log($scope.product);

}<br/>
```

**Post API**

```
router.post('/api/new-product',upload.any(),function(req, res, next){

  if(req.files){
    req.files.forEach(function(file){

      var filename = (new Date()).valueOf() + '-' + file.originalname;
      fs.rename(file.path,'public/images/'+ filename, function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        //Save to mongoose
        var product = new Products({
          productName: req.body.productName,
          productDescription: req.body.productDescription,
          productThumbnail: filename

        });
        product.save(function(err, result){
          if(err){}
            res.json(result);
        });

      });
    });
  }
})
```

I am able to save these values to mongoose:

```
productName: req.body.productName,
          productDescription: req.body.productDescription,
          productThumbnail: filename
```

But for **productStock** I am unable to post data to mongoose.
For productStock I did like this:
`productStock:[{size = req.body.productStock.size}]`
Even when I log `req.body.productStock.size`, I am getting undefined.
But I could see productStock in angular console.
**Why this happening Angular is binding data, but node js is getting as `undefined` that too few fields?**
Please help..

Comment: what is the log of req.body.productStock?

Comment: it's [object object]

Comment: share your angular template  or structure of $scope.product

Comment: Added Angular template in question.

Comment: i think you will get data inside req.body.productStock[0].size you can loop  through req.body.productStock and build your object for saving

Comment: I logged `req.body.productStock[0].size`, getting **undefined**